# How two nest react route correct?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import { Route,  BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_wfcgvw`} basename={`${parentPath}/e10`}>
          <Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_1jvdgd`} exact path={`/index`} component={ME10Index} />
          <Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_1jvdgd`} path={`/invoice`} component={ME10Invoice} />
          <Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_1jvdgd`} path={`/statistic`} component={ME10Statistic} />
          <Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_cg92wc`} exact path={'/mine'}component={ME10Mine} />
          <Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_cg92wc`} exact path={'/mine/mail'} component={ME10MailSetting} />
</Router>
```

As you see I have a router like this I want to optimize this part:

from

```
<Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_cg92wc`} exact path={'/mine'}component={ME10Mine} />
<Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_cg92wc`} exact path={'/mine/mail'} component={ME10MailSetting} />
```

to

```
<Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_ucqhv6`} path="/mine">
            <Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_cg92wc`} path={''}component={ME10Mine} />
            <Route weId={`${this.props.weId || ''}_cg92wc`} path={'mail'} component={ME10MailSetting} />
</Route>
```

Shortly, I want to make the route brief and include nested information. How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting)?

Comment: @Taxel I have read this post. For now, I encounter an issue that the route works not correctly when I nest them. I posted my code.

Comment: You need `<Switch>` elements around multiple routes